# Android Bluetooth Paring Input Device

Tags: android, input, bluetooth, input-devices, pairing-heap

I am trying to make a pairing by code and it works only for normal devices. If I use a bluetooth scanner it pairs with it but the device doesn't work till I go to android settings and select the Input Device checkbox. How can I do this by code?

Thank you.

Here is my pairing code:

```
public static BluetoothSocket createL2CAPBluetoothSocket(String address, int psm){
    return createBluetoothSocket(TYPE_L2CAP, -1, false,false, address, psm);
}
// method for creating a bluetooth client socket
private static BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(
        int type, int fd, boolean auth, boolean encrypt, String address, int port){
    try {
        Constructor<BluetoothSocket> constructor = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
                int.class, int.class,boolean.class,boolean.class,String.class, int.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        BluetoothSocket clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket)
                constructor.newInstance(type,fd,auth,encrypt,address,port);
        return clientSocket;
    }catch (Exception e) { return null; }
}

private void doPair(final BluetoothDevice device, final int deviceTag) {
    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond",
                (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot pair device", e);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(
                        BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE,
                        BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                final int prevState = intent.getIntExtra(
                        BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE,
                        BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED
                        && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Paired with new device");
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onBluetoothPairedDeviceChange(bluetoothAdapter
                                .getBondedDevices().iterator().next()
                                .getName(), deviceTag);
                    }
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE
                        && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cannot pair with new device");
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onBluetoothStatusChange(BluetoothHelper.IDLE_STATUS);
                    }
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                }
            }
        }

    };

    IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First,if your target version after API 19 , you can use `BluetoothDevice.createBond()` to pair the device directly without use reflection.
**Following methods only work on devices before android 6.0!(After 6.0, system will do some caller check to avoid outer app to call these methods）**

```
 BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(MainActivity.this, new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
     @Override
     public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
          Class<?> clazz = null;
          try {
               clazz = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputDevice");
               Object obj = clazz.cast(proxy);
               Method connectMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("connect",BluetoothDevice.class);
               boolean resultCode = (boolean) connectMethod.invoke(obj,device);
               Method setPriority = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setPriority",BluetoothDevice.class,int.class);
               setPriority.invoke(obj,device,1000);
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }

     @Override
     public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
             Log.d("wtf","onservice disconnected "+profile);
     }
},INPUT_DEVICE);

final int INPUT_DEVICE = 4; // this is hidden memeber in BluetoothDevice
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Please update if anything extra need to add.